# Dynamically filtering with __icontains from input field

Tags: python, django

I want to filter my fields in a model dynamically from a form input.

Already searched a lot but did not find something suitable. As i am fairly new to django and all this stuff i might not see some obvious stuff.

The form defines the field to search in and what to search(filter).

This should lead to a url like  `http://localhost:8000/app/search/?col=id&q=1234`

In my view i would like to modify the get_queryset() function with a filter like this:

```py
   def get_queryset(self):
        query1 = self.request.GET.get('q')
        query2 = self.request.GET.get('col')
        object_list = mymodel.objects.filter(
            Q(query2__icontains = query1)
        )
```

Is this possible?

Moe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do it like this.

```
>>> query = {f'{query2}__icontains': query1}
>>> object_list = mymodel.objects.filter(**query)
```